# Action Script 3 - Posting a JSON to a RESTful server

Tags: ajax, json, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to POST a simple JSON object to a RESTfull server using the following code:

```
var messages:Array = new Array ();  
messages.push ({"name":"MyName"});

var vars: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.data   = JSON.stringify(messages);

var urlRequest:URLRequest= new URLRequest("http://localhost:8080/xxx/player/createAccount");
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = vars;
var hdr:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(hdr);

_urlLoader = new URLLoader();
_urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLDataLoaded);
_urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

My object is a simple one,  it contains a field called {"name" : "MyName"}

The server fails to recognize the request's data.

the request on the network monitor shows this:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/xxx/player/createAccount HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 42
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:8080
X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/15.0.0.223
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8080/xxx/flashClient/lobby.swf
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1841C3CBE7511794A4EEF8A1A0BD56DD

data=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22MyName%22%7D%5D
```

A working post request looks like this on the network monitor tool:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/xxx/player/createAccount HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 20
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://cdjfedloinmbppobahmonnjigpmlajcd
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1841C3CBE7511794A4EEF8A1A0BD56DD

{ "name" : "MyName"}
```

Any ideas how can I make the first request perform like the second one?

Comment: How did you generate the 2nd POST request?

Comment: Thanks for informing me i forgot to add my code:) I edited the post.

Comment: The problem is you're turning your JSON into a string, then stuffing that string into a `URLVariables` object which then encodes the string. You don't want the string JSON encoded, so just assign the data property of the Request the stringified JSON directly. (I think that is what @Crabar's answer is trying to explain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're content type is `application/json`, then you don't want to use `URLVariables` for your data:

```
//this is causing the problem because it's encoding your JSON string so it's url safe.
var vars: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.data   = JSON.stringify(messages);
```

Instead, assign the stringified JSON directly to the `URLRequest`'s `data` property like in the following example:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest= new URLRequest("http://localhost:8080/xxx/player/createAccount");
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = JSON.stringify({"name":"MyName"});
var hdr:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(hdr);

_urlLoader = new URLLoader();
_urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLDataLoaded);
_urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

P.S. There is a good [tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/) that can help with understanding REST paradigm.